# How to open and manipulate pictures fast and efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Recently I have tried my hand at machine learning with Tensorflow in Python, as my first project with both these products, to prepare for my next semester, but I have run into an issue regarding runtimes, and perhaps with my general understanding.

I want to create a program that:

1. Loads a picture (From a path)
2. Uses a loss function and gradient decent to turn all the pixels more green
3. Outputs the picture again.

The good news is I did manage to do just that:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
input = "pic.png"
output = "output.png"

file = Image.open(path)
picture = np.array(file, np.float16)
tenarray = tf.Variable(picture) #takes 20+ sec to run

greenPic = np.empty([len(picture[:, 1]), len(picture[1]), 3], dtype=np.float16)
greenPic[:, :, 1] = 250
comparisonPic = tf.Variable(greenPic) #takes 20+ sec to run


picComparison = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(comparisonPic * tf.log(tenarray)))

rate = 0.05
trainingStep = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(rate).minimize(picComparison)

with tf.Session() as sesh:
    sesh.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) #Sets our variables, gets ready to run.
    for i in range(100):
        sesh.run(trainingStep)

resultArray = sesh.run(tenarray)

#Save picture
```

Problem is, that code takes 45 secounds to run, which is basically 2*22 sec of idling and ~1 sec of actual computation.

I have made faster versions but they all fail to manipulate the picture, or refuse to compile.
Does anyone have a good idea how to do this, that is more efficient?

Comment: Where do you get those numbers (44 seconds of idling and 1 second of computation)?  Where in your program does idling occur?

Comment: I got them by adding timings ( time.time() ) and measuring things out. 

The lines that take 20. sec+ are the lines that assign a tf.Variable to the names tenarray, and the comparisonPic.

Comment: @Nodine - why in the world do you think that's idling? Training a model is the most computationally intensive part of it all.

Comment: @zwer isn't the line that says "sesh.run(trainingStep)" the line that does the actual training, because that takes about 0.5 sec total for 100 iterations.

Comment: @Nodine - wrong expression - it takes time to build the model(s), assuming your numpy array is huge. Although it certainly shouldn't take 20 seconds on a decent machine unless you're working with terapixel images.

Comment: @zwer for refernece, the picture in question is a normal 'HD' two megapixel 1920x1080 png image, so about 6 million values iirc.

Comment: How much RAM does that machine has? What I can see is that you are not calling `close()` on those files and maybe that is affecting your performance (make sure to clean unused objects)

Comment: I have 32 gb @GrayCygnus - and my gpu is a 780ti

Comment: Is using `float8` an issue for you? What is the resolution of your original picture? (If the resolution is ob 8 bit you dont need `float16`)

Comment: [Sci-kit Image](http://scikit-image.org/) Really easy loads, no idea about timing though.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBrown I might try that recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself, so I will comment here if anyone happens to run into the same problem for some reason.

The problem was using tf.float16's instead of tf.float32's for the image tensors, changing this has made the code above run 50 times faster for me.

So:

```
picture = tf.Variable(np.asarray(file, np.float32), tf.float32)
...
comparisonPic = tf.Variable(np.asarray(greenPic), tf.float32)
```